# Linux find command- display files older than 7 days - without using timestamp

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

there is process which creates files in every half and hour.
I want to remove files older than 7 days.

But when I'm running this command its removing file older than seven days from current timestamp of running instant, But I don't want to remove by timestamp I just want to remove all files created on or before that day.

Command:

```
find <file_path> -mtime +6 -name 'sample_file01*.txt' -delete
```

If I run this command on 09-11-2018 at 11:30, It will remove files of 02-11-2018 11:00 and before.
I just want to remove all files of 02-11-2018 as well.

Should i use different command or some modification required in above find command

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04, `find` has a `-daystart` option which allows you to do what you want:

```
find <file_path> -daystart -mtime +5 -name 'sample_file01*.txt' -delete
```

You need to reduce the number of days by one for the range you need.

If you don't have this option (eg on OSX), you can use `-mmin`:

```
secsnow=$(date +%s)
minstoday=$(($secsnow%86400/60))
minsago=$((5*1440+$minstoday))
find <file_path> -mmin +$minsago -name 'sample_file01*.txt' -delete
```

I've show this in stages, so that the arithmetic is clear, but it could all be done with a single arithmetic expression as the parameter:

```
... -mmin $(($(date +%s)%86400/60+5*1440)) ...
```

Comment: Thank you AFH, using '-daystart' worked.
Very much helpful. you saved me ;)